# DIV height set as percentage of screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to set a parent DIV as 70% of the full 100% screen height. I've set the following CSS but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
body {
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.header {
height: 70%;
}
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to be working though and the header isn't 70% of the screen size. Any advice?

Answer (score 240):

Try using Viewport Height

```
div {
    height:100vh; 
}
```

It is already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window) in detail

Comment: Works surprisingly well across browsers and devices.

Comment: That's `window.innerHeight`, not `screen.height`

Answer (score 7):

make position `absolute` for that div.

http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/KkKeZ/

Answer (score 6):

This is the **solution** ,

Add the `html` also to `100%`

```
html,body {

   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it based on the screen height, and not the window height:

```js
const height = 0.7 * screen.height

// jQuery
$('.header').height(height)

// Vanilla JS
document.querySelector('.header').style.height = height + 'px'

// If you have multiple <div class="header"> elements
document.querySelectorAll('.header').forEach(function(node) {
  node.style.height = height + 'px'
})
```

Comment: THIS is the answer that works for me in Cordova for setting the toolbars to the exact height and KEEPING them that height when the soft keyboard is pulled into view. Before, the toolbars were set to a percentage of height and got smaller as the viewport decreased in height, but after setting their height with this, they are the same size when the keyboard is pulled into view. Combine with "adjustResize" in your AndroidManifest file for using a top and bottom toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

By using absolute positioning, you can make `<body>` or `<form>` or `<div>`, fit to your browser page. For example:

```
<body style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px;">
```

and then simply put a `<div>` inside it and use whatever percentage of either `height` or `width` you wish

```
<div id="divContainer" style="height: 100%;">
```