# Modify function to display max windows height minus 20%

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to modify JavaScript (jQuery, Google Maps v.3) to get the size of #mao_canvas only 80% of the screen height, but I can't undestand what to modify in tihs function. Can anyone help me with this?
The basic idea is to get 80% height of #map_canvas.

```
$(function(){
  $("#map_canvas").css("height",$(window).height() + 'px');
  initialize();
});
```

Comment: is this what you mean?  $(function(){
  $("#map_canvas").css("height",($(window).height()*80/100) + 'px');
  initialize();
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you mean?
 `$(function(){
  $("#map_canvas").css("height",($(window).height()*80/100) + 'px');
  initialize();
});`

Comment: this should be a comment not answer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain, what is happening here: `height()*80/100) + 'px'`
Why px is still there if we are talking about percents?

Comment: the person who asked himself is confused

Comment: $(window).height() gives you the actual height in pixels at any given time. all you need to do is extract 80% from this value. then you'll get the actual pixel value of 80%. all there is left to do is add px to this actual value

Comment: Got it. And why this was not working?
`$("#map_canvas").css("height","80%");`

Comment: I meant clicking on th V sign on the answer:). regarding you new question - It should work if you build your html tags and css right. look at this:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843391/div-height-set-as-percentage-of-screen).